# Laravel 5.7 Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController does not exist

Tags: laravel-5

When I add `['verify' => true]` parameter to web auth routes like so

```
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);
```

I cannot see routes when calling

```
$ php artisan route:list
```

instead of a table I'm getting:

> ReflectionException  : Class App\Http\Controllers\Auth\VerificationController does not exist

And it is truth, I don't have a file called `VerificationController` nowhere on my computer.

I'm currently on laravel/framework version 5.7.20

Comment: Have you run `php artisan make:auth`? If you upgraded from 5.6, you may want to start a new laravel app run `make:auth` and then copy the new Controller into your upgraded 5.7 instance.

Comment: Yes, I upgraded from 5.6, but No, I did not run `make:auth`, the [Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade) does not say that I need running `php artisan make:auth`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the [Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/upgrade) when Upgrading To 5.7.0 From 5.6
suggests to make a controller manually in the
**Email Verification** section.

this is  a [VerificationController.php](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.7/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/VerificationController.php) that officially should be used in this case

Comment: This is basically the same thing as what I said you needed to do, but I thought the Controller only appeared when you run `make:auth`

Comment: Yes, thank you. This advise I got as an answer to my [issue on github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/27149)